# Multiple function calling?

Tags: c, function

Hi extremely new to programming. Just want to know if for example I have a function called void blink(void). If I write a code

```
2 * blink();
```

is it the same as

```
blink();
blink();
```

?

Comment: Did you compile/run this code? What happened? No, it won't call it twice.

Comment: Yes it did not. How do i do it then? I have a variable 'num' and I want the function to be called as much as the num value

Comment: You should use loops.

Comment: For loop from 1 to `num` (or, more traditionally, 0 to `num-1`).

Comment: How do I write codes in comments?

Comment: @Fiidisks use triple backtick `

Comment: Please take a C tutorial. SO can not and doesn't want to teach people programming from scratch! As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```c
2 * blink();
```

No, this will not call `blink()` 2 times, this will multiply 2 with the value that `blink()` returns. Because `blink()` is `void` (that means `blink()` doesn't return anything), this will cause an error.

> I have a variable 'num' and I want the function to be called as much
> as the num value

You should use a `for` loop. For example:

```c
for(int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
/* this is the same as for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i) */
{
    blink();
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. Is it also correct to put  i<num if my i=0 ?

Comment: @Fiidisks Yep, both of those is identical (in logic)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where you took this syntax from, but it will not call the function twice. It will multiply the function return value by two.

```
int blink(void)
{
    return 5;
}

int main(void)
{
    int result;

    result = 2 * blink();
    printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4nrGj3M6W

if `blink` has `void` return type it will simple not compile.

Another way of multiple calling function using function pointer:

```
void blink(void)
{
    printf("BLIMK!!!\n");
}

void callMultiple(void (*func)(void), size_t ntimes)
{
    while(ntimes--) func();
}


int main(void)
{
    size_t times;

    if(scanf("%zu", &times) == 1)
    {
        callMultiple(blink, times);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jWEd9hnK9